# ViewPager circle indicator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to create a UI where there are 4 fragments. The first two fragments should have a view pager indicator like image 1, while the last two must have indicators as image 2.
[image]
[image: Image 2]

As of now, I've been using the normal ViewPager/CircleIndicator combo. But the circle indicator is always on the bottom similar to image 2(yeah, duh). How would I achieve the above UI?
Do I create a custom viewpager?

Any help/nudging me in the right direction are appreciated!

Edit:

Sign up activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/splashbg"
android:weightSum="4"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="biz.wrinklefree.wrinklefree.SignUpActivity">

<biz.wrinklefree.wrinklefree.CustomViewPager
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">

</biz.wrinklefree.wrinklefree.CustomViewPager>

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/circleindicator"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator>

</LinearLayout>
```

One of the fragment(need to add more elements like text fields and buttons only):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="biz.wrinklefree.wrinklefree.UserRegOne">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textColorHint="#000"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clik"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you paste your XML ?

Comment: I've edited the code to contain XML layouts for both fragment and the activity calling it.